# JavaScript defining object keys from a variable value

Tags: javascript, object

I know you can do
    object[key] = 
But is there any way to do
    [Object]key =
And
    object[object]key =
As what I'm working on I need to be able to set and access data from objects in that sense.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Like if I wanted to set a key that was an object like user["Alex"].money = 35

Comment: @ZephyrONE—that should work fine. What have you tried? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @RobGvar object = {};
var keyData = "keyData";
object[keyData].key = "alright";
console.log(object.keyData.key);

Comment: I expected it to log alright but it was just a syntax error.

Comment: @ZephyrONE: You forgot to create `object[keyData] = {}` first (before creating a property on that object). It's not a syntax error, it's a ReferenceError.

Comment: Yah... I changed that it is undefined now tho.

Comment: Your `console.log` logs the wrong variable. It needs to be `console.log(object[keyData].key)`, same as your assignment.